# jquery function after setTimeout

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I have a dropUp menu with the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var opened = false;
$("#menu_tab").click(function(){
    if(opened){
        $("#menu_box").animate({"top": "+=83px"}, "slow");
        setTimeout(function(){
                $("#menu_box").animate({"top": "+=83px"}, "slow");
                }, 2000);
                clearTimeout();
    }else{
        $("#menu_box").animate({"top": "-=83px"}, "slow");
    }
    $("#menu_content").slideToggle("slow");
    $("#menu_tab .close").toggle();
    opened = opened ? false : true;
});
});
```

So after clicking on the menu_tab, the menu drops up and stays up until clicked again, but I'd like a timeout so that after say 2 seconds the menu drops down again.

I've obviously got the coding wrong because the timeout isn't working. Any help would be appreciated!  TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to do something like this:

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/YFPey/

```
var opened = false;
var timeout;
$("#menu_tab").click(function() {
      // If there's a setTimeout running, clear it.
    if(timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = null;
    }
    if(opened) {
        $("#menu_box").animate({"top": "+=83px"}, "slow");
    } else {
        $("#menu_box").animate({"top": "-=83px"}, "slow");
             // Set a timeout to trigger a click that will drop it back down
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            timeout = null;
            $("#menu_tab").click();
        }, 2000);
    }
    $("#menu_content").slideToggle("slow");
    $("#menu_tab .close").toggle();
    opened = !opened;
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of clearTimeout() here is wrong.  You need to pass it a reference to the ID returned when you created that timer with setTimeout().

Can't say if that's causing your problem though (it probably isn't).  If you get anything in the Javascript error console that might help.

Answer (score 0):

Two things that stand out to me:

1. Because `opened` starts out as false, the timer only gets started on the second click.
2. In the timer handler, should you be updating `opened`.